# XStream can't alias fieldnames on deserialization to java

Tags: java, xstream

How does this make any sense? I provide an alias for "name", but it still doesn't work. I'm using XStream 1.4.5

> com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$UnknownFieldException:
>   No such field B.status

```
    public class B {
        public String name;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        XStream serializer = new XStream();
        serializer.alias("a", B.class);
        serializer.aliasField("status", String.class, "name");
        B obj = (B) serializer.fromXML("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?><a><status>true</status></a>");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter to `aliasField` should be the type that *declares* the field being aliased, not the type *of* the field.

```
serializer.aliasField("status", B.class, "name");
```